# Unable to run threaded java jar file on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with Java 1.7.0.45 using pacifist

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, jar, osx-snow-leopard

I have installed **Java 1.7.0_45** on **Mac OS X 10.6.8** using **Pacifist** [http://www.charlessoft.com/] however I am unable to run a jar file which I have downloaded. The jar file is a threaded application.

The error message I am getting is:

```
java -jar context.jar
2013-10-31 14:14:41.898 java[330:a07] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x109356390 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2013-10-31 14:14:41.900 java[330:a07] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x109356390 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
Trace/BPT trap
```

Is there anyway I can run the jar. I have set the JAVA_HOME path properly and java -version is showing 1.7.0_45 as the version.

The same application works properly on Windows Java 1.7.0_45 and also on Linux Java 1.7.

The web search for the solution and the given keywords return very few results and none of them have any specific solution in it. I am new to mac so I am not fully able to understand the issue.

Alternatively, is there anyway I can run Java from folder in Mac like I can do in windows and Linux by just extracting the Java contents and changing the JAVA_HOME. If that is possible then I should be able to run my JAR.

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of same problem while installing an application through jar file, my Java was not detected by the jar application installer, 
Over here I see that one of the method is not accessible, could be a same problem. But I am not very sure of it. 
make sure you have rt.jar in your JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ folder
In case you don't have then you are required to have it through the process of creation of symbolic link.

In the command below replace your_java_version with proper version matching your requirement.

```
sudo mkdir -p /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/<your_java_version>/Home/jre/lib
```

Go into the directory:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/<your_java_version>/Home/jre/lib/
```

Create symbolic link :

```
sudo ln -s ../../../Classes/classes.jar rt.jar
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix it for me. I already have rt.jar in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I get the exact same problem with MacOS 10.6.8 and JDK 7. In order to run the jar I had to use the System JRE which is 1.6.x (In my case I wanted to install Squirrel

> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar >squirrel-sql-3.6-MACOSX-install.jar